# WordPress custom URL and custom template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom template named "eshop". In there, it calls a separate API out from WordPress and clicking on a link returns something like : eshop/ABC-123/

Is there a way I can make all the URLs that contain the word "eshop" to use the custom template I have created?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step one: Pull the URI into a variable (http://webcheatsheet.com/php/get_current_page_url.php)

Step two: Search the variable string for the string you're looking for ([How do I check if a string contains a specific word in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words#4366748))

Step three: use an if statement (If variable includes string "eshop", include the template) with a PHP include statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using WordPress template, where I create the Page from the CMS. Thus unable to perform step (3) .

Comment: You tagged PHP so I thought you wanted to do this with PHP.